# Why did Lord Rama and Lord Krishna choose to born at (12 O'clock) day and night time respectively?

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, krishna, bhagavata-purana, rama

I have heard that Lord Rama was born at afternoon 12 O'clock (In day time) in Treta yuga. Same as in Dwapara yuga, Lord Krishna was born at mid night 12 O'clock (In night time). Both Lord Rama and Lord Krishna were avatara of Lord Vishnu, then what is the need of choosing specific time? They can born anytime, time never bond to gods as per my understanding.

- Why did Lord Rama and Lord Krishna choose to born at 12 O'clock in day and in night time respectively?
- What is significance of birth timing in both case?

We commonly perform Krishnastami pooja and Ramnavami pooja at same time which I mentioned. I have heard from my elders, *those people, who are in "Bhojan or external desires" were unaware of Lord Rama's birth and those people, who are in "Kama bhog" were unaware of Lord Krishna's birth.*

**Update:**
I got birth time (12 O'clock) details of Lord Rama and Lord Krishna from one of the article based on "Stotra mantranche vignyan"(page no.25) by Parampujya Swami Savitanand which is published by Prasad prakashan, Pune. Soft copy link for this is not available online, but from [here](http://bookganga.com/eBooks/Books/Details/5586247400647207423) get the hard copy. Scriptures are only defining that Lord Rama was born at mid-day and Lord Krishna was born at Midnight. Beside this I did not find any scriptural reference of exact birth time.

Comment: Good question. Here are other similar questions. Why did Rama choose to be born in Treta Yuga? Why did Rama choose to be born in Ayodhya? Why did Rama choose to be born in Dasharatha's Kingdom. Why did Krishna born to Vasudeva? Why did Krishna choose to be born in Dvapara Yuga? Why did Krishna choose to reveal Himself to Vasudevaji. Why did Krishna split Yamuna into two!! IMHO These are all simply memorable moments which God does when He takes birth in the world, so that people remember His stories and get liberated by remembering Him sir. Thank you.

Comment: +1 Good Question I think it might be because of specific graha dasha or kundali samikarana, so that lord can get best out of his manushya jeevan.

Comment: Where did you get that the idea that they were born at 12?

Comment: I got birth time (12 O'clock) details of Lord Rama and Lord Krishna from one of the article based on "Stotra mantranche vignyan"(page no.25) by Parampujya Swami Savitanand  which is published by Prasad prakashan, Pune. Soft copy link for this is not available online, but from here get the hard copy http://www.bookganga.com/eBooks/Books/Details/5586247400647207423 . Scriptures are only defining that Lord Rama was born at mid-day and Lord Krishna was born at Midnight. Beside this I did not find any scriptural reference of exact birth time. Do I need to change the question? Let me know.Thanks:)!!

Comment: Not so true, Mr. @Sai! You gave just fantasy words! It has full relativity with showing how to live in every worse moment coming in very common human life. I will definitely come with better and more near to correct answer.

Comment: Mr @Vikrant I feel you have misunderstood my comment. I am not trying to diminish the value of Sri Krishna and Sri Rama in their Avatar. Everybody knows that the incidents in their life was to set example for others. But questions such as 'why 12 o clock', 'why not 6 o clock', etc will not have any definite answer except that they are memorable moments. Anyways I am not quite able to understand what you meant by 'You gave just fantasy words'. Finally I am looking forward to your answer so that I can learn from you sir. Thank you for showing interest and all the best :) !!

Comment: **He takes birth in the world, so that people remember His stories**, I think these are fantasy words!!

Comment: GOD is not the Politician who needs to visit after every course of time; but he is the creator of world; he comes to save those, who work like, live like **Manu**'s son & are stuck in problem! not for those people who have forgotten him.

Comment: @Vikrant First of all, God is not a politician. God is a Father. Father comes to your room, to help you. Whether you remember or forget Him, he will come isn't it. Secondly I am very sorry to say you really need to read my comments again to understand what I am talking about. All I am saying is that God takes birth in the world, so that people remember His stories. That is definitely not my own fantasy. It is described in **Shrimad Bhagavatam**. There are many reasons why God takes birth. One of them is to teach lessons as you said. Another reason is for rememberance. All the best!!

Comment: @Vikrant As for why God takes birth, here is verse from Srimad Bhagavatam 1:8:31-35 which describes why Avatar is born from time and time again. One of the reasons is (1:8:35) - "And yet others say that You appeared to rejuvenate the devotional service of hearing, **remembering**, worshiping and so on in order that the conditioned souls suffering from material pangs might take advantage and gain **liberation**." Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21914/discussion-between-vikrant-and-sai).

Comment: At that time, was it really invented this timing system i-e of 12:00 O'clock and so on??

Comment: ~12 is abhjitlagna. Meridian time is considered highly auspicious and powerful.

Comment: The 24hr system and time zones were not present at Rama/Krishna’s time. For example, IST is one of the unique zones which has a 1/2 hour difference from GMT. If others had decided, these times would have been 12:30 or 11:30 depending on the difference chosen. So the fact of exact 12am/noon has not basis.

Answer (score 7):

Well, I wouldn't say they were born at 12 o'clock. Rather they were born when the sun was highest in the sky (Rama) and at the darkest part of night (Krishna). We often say 12 o'clock because that is usually when the sun is the highest in the sky or the darkest part of night, but not always. 
I don't think there is a reason for Rama, but there is one for Lord Krishna. Krishna was least likely to be seen while being transported across the Yamuna river at the darkest hour so he was born in the darkest hour to refrain from being seen.

Answer (score 2):

The noon time/midnight when sun is exactly at top/below at your Meridian is considered to be Abhijit Muhurt. The reigning deity of Nakshtara Abhijit is Vishnu and has powerful connotations.

Comment: This sounds like comment rather than answer, visit [answer] and cite some sources